# Dart, overriding not equal operator gives error

Tags: dart

I've been developing dart(flutter) for some while and I came upon this Error. I was creating a custom class that had several operator overrides. For explanation purposes, the class looks like this.

```
class CustomObject {
  int big;
  int small;
  CustomObject(this.big, this.small);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other is CustomObject) {
      return big == other.big && small == other.small;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => big.hashCode ^ small.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator !=(Object other) {
  // Error: The string '!=' isn't user-definable operator.
    if (other is CustomObject) {
      return big != other.big || small != other.small;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

The error occurs on the != operator override. Looking at this website https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-in-dart/ it says that you can override != operator. I could not find any other source that documents overriding this operator.

My question is, 1. are you supposed to override != in the first place? 2. if so, is are any restrictions on overriding != operators?

Comment: No you aren't supposed to override `!=`, the language tour says that `e1 != e2` is syntactic sugar for `!(e1 == e2)`, so overriding `==` will also give you `!=`. https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#_operators

Comment: @mmcdon20 Logically, that makes sense.  Thank you.